# Disable temporarily forward swipe only in uiPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, installation, uipageviewcontroller

I'm writing a series of settings / setup screens using uiPageViewController (images at the bottom). The user configures stuff, and swipe to the next screen, and so on. But I would like to lock / disable / block the forward swipe until the settings has been accomplished by the user in the current screen.

I tried:

1) uiPageViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false. It blocks everything in the screen, including the backward swipe. I want to block only the forward.

2)

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if !forwardSwipeEnabled {
        return nil
    }
    var index  = contentViewControllers.indexOf(viewController)
    index += 1
    return contentViewControllers[index]
}
```

to `return nil` when `forwardSwipeEnabled` is set to `false`, and it works, but the forward swipe remains blocked even after I change forwardSwipeEnabled = true because UIPageViewController already called this function when the scene showed up on the screen.

If I go back and forward again, the function gets called again and it works.

**----- edit -----**

Calling `pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)` with the current view controller doesn't refresh or call the function again.

3) Only append the next screen (UIViewcontroller), after the user finishes, but the same problem as 2) occurs.

**----- edit -----**

4) I can get the gestureRecognizers with `view.subviews.first?.gestureRecognizers`, but setting them `gestureRecognize.enabled = false` blocks both forward and reverse. There aren't different gestureRecognizers for each to block selectively.

5) Intercepting the gesture and eating it when direction is forward or letting it run, with the bottom code when backward doesn't work because the user can start the swipe backward, trigger the function return and finish forward.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for view: UIView in pageViewController!.view.subviews {
        if (view is UIScrollView) {
            let scrollView = (view as! UIScrollView)
            self.scrollViewPanGestureRecognzier = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
            self.scrollViewPanGestureRecognzier.delegate = self
            scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewPanGestureRecognzier)
        }
    }
}

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == scrollViewPanGestureRecognzier {
        guard let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer else { return false }
        let velocity = panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(view)
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(view)
        if translation.x < 0 {
            return true
        }
        if velocity.x < 0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

---

Example screen:

[image: example] [image]

Comment: "But I would like to lock / disable / block the forward swipe until the settings has been accomplished by the user in the current screen." Your basic strategy is right. The `viewControllerAfterViewController` delegate method should simply return `nil` to prevent forward swiping.

Comment: @matt , As stated in 2), it blocks, but doesn't unblock, after I change the environment variable that told it to block. And I can't refresh the framework, so it calls the function again to unblock it. It remains stuck, unless the user goes back to previous page and forward again to the page that was locked.

Comment: Right, this must be because the runtime says to itself, Hey, I already know the answer for this view controller, so no need for me to call this method again. But that is why @kocakmstf's suggestion makes sense. You need to substitute another view controller, yourself, supplying a _new instance_ of the same view controller, so that the delegate method gets called again.

Comment: It makes sense, but doesn't work. I already did it. The function doesn't get called again. :-(

Answer (score 0):

just as an suggestion you may reload datasource with `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion` after your job is done. This should fix your next page.
Its obj-c code. it should has same code in swift.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Doesn't call again the "viewControllerAfterViewController" function. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the solution for these years?
I've found only one: immediately go back if forward is forbidden:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
    let currentPage = orderedViewControllers!.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
    if !nextButton.isEnabled && currentPage > pageControl.currentPage {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.05, execute: { 
            self.setViewControllers([self.orderedViewControllers![self.pageControl.currentPage]], direction: .reverse, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```